# Use PyWPS with GRASS and Space-Time-Datacubes

Tags: python, grass-gis, wps, pywps

I'm a complete novice with PyWPS, so I'd be happy about any pointer and help. My issue is, that I want to write a process that calculates the min, max and mean of a  Spacetime -Datacube (of NDVIs), created in GRASS-GIS, for two date-ranges. For example, I'd like to compare the mean NDVI from August to December and from January to June.

My code so far looks like this:

```
import os
from pywps import Process, LiteralInput, LiteralOutput

class ndvi_index(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        inputs = [LiteralInput('start', 'Start date (eg. 2019-03-01)',
                               data_type='string'),
                  LiteralInput('end', 'End date (eg. 2019-04-01)',
                               data_type='string'),
                  LiteralInput('start2', 'Start date 2 (eg. 2019-03-01)',
                               data_type='string'),
                  LiteralInput('end2', 'End date 2(eg. 2019-03-01)',
                               data_type='string'),     

        ]
        outputs = [LiteralOutput('stats', 'Computed ndvi statistics',
                                 data_type='string')
        ]

        super(ndvi_index, self).__init__(
            self._handler,
            identifier='ndvi',
            version='0.1',
            title="Sentinel-2 NDVI Calculator",
            abstract='The Process will compute the average NDVI '                  
            profile='',
            inputs=inputs,
            outputs=outputs,
            store_supported=True,
            status_supported=True,
            grass_location="/home/user/grassdata/location"
        )

    def check_date(self, date_str):
        from datetime import datetime

        d = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
        if d.year != 2019:
            #raise Exception("Only year 2019 allowed")
            pass

    def _handler(self, request, response):
        from subprocess import PIPE
        import grass.script as gs
        from grass.pygrass.modules import Module
        from grass.exceptions import CalledModuleError

        ######## Date 1
        start = request.inputs['start'][0].data
        end = request.inputs['end'][0].data
        self.check_date(start)
        self.check_date(end)

        ####### Date 2
        start2 = request.inputs['start2'][0].data
        end2 = request.inputs['end2'][0].data
        self.check_date(start2)
        self.check_date(end2)

        output1 = 'ndvi1'
        output2 = "ndvi2"
   
        # be silent
        os.environ['GRASS_VERBOSE'] = '0'

        try:
            Module('t.rast.series',
                   input='ndvi@PERMANENT',
                   output=output1,
                   method='average',
                   where="start_time > '{start}' and start_time < '{end}'".format(
                       start=start, end=end
            ))
            Module('t.rast.series',
                   input='ndvi@PERMANENT',
                   output=output2,
                   method='average',
                   where="start_time > '{start}' and start_time < '{end}'".format(
                       start=start2, end=end2
            ))
        except CalledModuleError:
            raise Exception('Unable to compute statistics')

        ret = Module('r.univar',
                     flags='g',
                     map=output1,
                     stdout_=PIPE
        )
        ret2 = Module('r.univar',
                     flags='g',
                     map=output2,
                     stdout_=PIPE
        )

        stats = gs.parse_key_val(ret.outputs.stdout)
        stats2 = gs.parse_key_val(ret2.outputs.stdout)
        
        outstr = 'Min1: {0:.1f};Max1: {1:.1f};Mean1: {2:.8f}; \n Min2 {0:.1f};Max2: {1:.1f}; Mean2: {2:.8f}'.format(
            float(stats['min']), float(stats['max']), float(stats['mean']), float(stats2["min"]), float(stats2["max"]), float(stats2["mean"]))

        response.outputs['stats'].data = outstr

        return response
```

I know this is not really nice. However, I then start the server and call:

http://localhost:5000/wps?request=Execute&service=WPS&identifier=ndvi&version=1.0.0&datainputs=start=2019-07-01;end=2019-12-01;start2=2020-01-01;end2=2020-06-01

And it somehow works, but the results not only doesn't look good it's always the same for the two data-ranges.
Any ideas on what could be done completely different?:)

Comment: To what PyWPS is concerned, this is about it. Are you sure the results are incorrect? I would rather suspect the data.

Comment: Hi:) Thank you very much! This already helped a lot, because I wasn't sure about how to handle two input-ranges and print the see the output of both. But you are absolutely right. The data might be a little strange, but now I at least know that this goes in the right direction:) Thanks a lot

Comment: Just to the aim: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/t.rast.univar.html calculates the min, max and mean of a spacetime - datacube.